# Probability of an event occuring in an interval

Tags: probability

Suppose I just installed a light bulb for a cost $x$.
I need the cost I will incur in the next **5 years** in the following scenarios

(i) the bulb is likely to burn out once every 0.5 to 1 year

(ii) the bulb is likely to burn out one every 14 days to 0.5 year

(iii) the bulb is likely to burn out once every 0 to 14 days

I have not taken a probability course; and I am guessing there is a straight forward formula to calculate this...?

Comment: What do you mean by "likely to burn out"

Comment: @PeterForeman Likely to have to be replaced -- I'm trying to estimate how much we're gonna "likely" have to pay in the next five years in each of the scenarios

Comment: Is each bulb equally likely to burn out at any time within the given intervals?

Comment: It's just the one bulb and for each interval I am investigating, it's most likely to burn out once

Answer (score 1):

i) The bulb could burn out between $5$ to $10$ times in $5$ years so the cost can be anywhere from $5x$ to $10x$.

ii) Similarly, the bulb could burn out anywhere between $10$ to $130$ times in $5$ years costing between $10x$ and $130x$.

iii) In this case it is possible for you to need any amount of bulbs greater than $130$ in the $5$ year span as the bulbs can burn out in $0$ days. So, the cost of repair is any value greater than or equal to $130x$.